# Having issues in doing a Custom Validation for a GUID property in API asp.NET core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This is the class in which **I'm trying to validate the serialnumber** property(you can find it in the **code below named as NumerodiSerie**). I'm testing it with CRUD operations, in particular a POST.

The main problem is if I start the program and try to stop it in my validation function it simply won't enter in it cause swagger gives me an error before which is the following:

**the JSON value cannot be converted in system.guid**.

It only enters my validate function when I have a valid Guid(I think that I have this error because I was trying to test it(by deleting one number from the guid and so on) in order to see if my validation function worked).

```
public class Smartphone
{
    public string Produttore { get; set; }

    public string Modello { get; set; }

    [Range(1,100, ErrorMessage ="la ram non è compresa tra 1 e 100")]
    public int DimensioniRam { get; set; }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(Validator),"Validazionearchiviazione")]
    public int Memoria { get; set; }

    [Range(0,2, ErrorMessage ="la cpu non è compresa tra 0 e 2")]
    public ProduttoreProcessore CpuMaker { get; set; }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(Validator),"ValidateGuid")]
    public Guid NumerodiSerie { get; set; }
}
```

**POST**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateSmartphone(Smartphone s)
    {                                                                    
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();//auto generating GUID
        s.NumerodiSerie = g;//serialnumber property
        if (_cantinetta.Any(x => x.NumerodiSerie == s.NumerodiSerie))
        {
            return new 
            HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
            throw new Exception("/error");//errorcontroller
        }
        else
        {
            _cantinetta.Add(s);//_cantinetta is the list in which I store data
            Serializzajson();//serialize the json and writes it in a file
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

**CUSTOM VALIDATION METHOD**

```
 public static ValidationResult ValidateGuid(Guid value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        
        if (value.ToString().Length < 36 || validationContext.ObjectType != typeof(Guid) || 
         validationContext.ObjectType == typeof(Guid) && 
         validationContext.ObjectType.ToString().Length < 36)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("not a valid GUID");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;

    }
```

I was tryng to do this in the method but it doesn't work as I would expected. any suggestion? the custom validation is a new topic for me and I'm studyng C# since 6 months so I'm a newbie. dunno why it is formatted like that in this question.I didn't write it like that and also this is my first question in this fantastic place.
Have a Fantastic day.
Edward.

Comment: So this works, but only when is valid and not when GUID is incorrect, is that correct?

Comment: yes it is. it only enters this function when I have a valid GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just do:

```
if (!Guid.TryParse(textValue, out var id) || id == Guid.Empty)
{
   // Not a GUID or empty
}
// id is now a guid.
```

Comment: I will try It. I thought about it but I wanted to do it by doing a custom validation :) for checking multiple conditions, such as empty Guid, not valid Guid and so on. Also wanted to do it with the ValidationContext although I'm not sure if everything I wrote above is correct. I'll definitely consider your answer too as it Look very clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no need to check the post value is Guid or not in the custom validation method, since the asp.net core model binder will check it automatically. Besides, if the model binder finds the value is not the right guid type, it will not go to the custom validation and directly add the modelstate error.

Like below:

[image]

Comment: oh ok. but what If the user tryes to insert a Guid or a like looking Guid that I didn't generate it. It will be valid Isn't it? so without the custom validation how can I remove to the user the possibility to change the Guid that I have generated? is there a way to manage this possibility? thank you. I generate automatically the Guid everytime the user goes in the Post method.

Comment: In my opinion, you could also check the guid in the custom validation method to make sure this GUID is valid or not.